# Scope problems in eventHandler

Tags: javascript, jquery

So javascript isn't really my forte. I'm putting a simple click event handler on some elements and it works fine if I manually attach the handler on each element that needs it like so:

```
$('#box-content-fr-tab').click(function () {
    switchLang('menu', 'fr');
});

$('#box-content-nl-tab').click(function () {
     switchLang('menu', 'nl');
});

//etc

function switchLang(currentField, currentLang){
    $('#box-'+currentField+'-'+currentLang+'-tab').addClass('active');
    $('#box-'+currentField+'-'+currentLang).addClass('active show');

    for(oLang in $.object.langues){
        if(oLang !== currentLang && oLang !== 'end'){
            $('#box-'+currentField+'-'+oLang+'-tab').removeClass('active');
     $('#box-'+currentField+'-'+oLang).removeClass('active show');
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to not manually attach the onClick handler on each element but when I naively try to loop through a list, I run into scope problems with my `currentLang` and `currentField` variables. I tried something like:

```
for(lang in this.langues){
    if(lang !== 'end'){
       var currentLang = lang;
        $('#box-content-'+lang+'-tab').click(function(){
            switchLang(currentField, currentLang);
        });
    }
}
```

but it's not working. Any ideas on how to make it more dynamic?

Comment: Change `var currentLang = ...` to `let currentLang = ...`. Alternatively, avoid the loop entirely by putting the same class on all the elements and storing the language value in a `data` attribute. Then you can read that attribute out on click.

Comment: As @RoryMcCrossan mentioned, use [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let). [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) is defined in the `functional scope`, whereas `let` is defined in the `block scope`.

Comment: @Alex `var is defined in the global scope`, you of course meant `functional scope`, and let is `block scope`..

Comment: Yeah @Keith, just different wording, same idea. +

Comment: Why you create new variable `currentLang` at all?

Comment: True. It's not needed unless you need some processing done on it.

Comment: Could I ask if you manually insert `'end'` into your `lang` array? Or are you trying to iterate until the end of the array?

Comment: This should be done without relying on IDs at all IMHO. Use a class to select the elements to bind the click handler to - and place the rest of the necessary information in `data-` attributes. Then this needs _one_ handler function, and no loops at all.

Comment: for..in iterates over `object` properties so I think it looks something like `{ul: {}, en: {}}`

Comment: The 'end' element is used somewhere else. Creating the variable currentLang was my poor attempt at fixing the scope problem. As for using classes rather than ID's, it's an option, but there's a lot of other pieces of code acting on those elements, and they're not my work. Using let, solves the problem, thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use something like this, it should work fine since lang is just a string as I understand but you should remember that `let` is not supported in some old browsers:

```
for(let lang in this.langues){
    if(lang !== 'end'){
        $('#box-content-'+lang+'-tab').click(function(){
            switchLang(currentField, lang);
        });
    }
}
```

If you're trying to iterate until the end of the array/object, you don't even need to check for `lang !== 'end'`, Hence:

---

```
for(let lang in this.langues){
    $('#box-content-'+lang+'-tab').click(function(){
        switchLang(currentField, lang);
    });
}
```

Comment: I was supposed to edit my own post and accidentally pressed on yours without thinking :)

Comment: I approved it as is :)

Answer (score 2):

As others stated, you can use `let` keyword, in your case you don't even need the variable unless you need some processing done on it.

---

```
this.langues.forEach((lang) => {
  if (lang !== 'end') {
    $('#box-content-' + lang + '-tab').click(() => {
      switchLang(currentField, lang);
    });
  }
});
```

Else, if you're iterating until the end of the array, you don't need to check for `'end'` unless you need it for something else, Hence:

---

```
this.langues.forEach((lang) => {
    $('#box-content-'+lang+'-tab').click(function(){
        switchLang(currentField, lang);
    });
)};
```

Answer (score 2):

Better do something simple like

```
$('[id^="box-content-"]').click(function () {//one single event for all your languages
    var lang = this.id.split('-')[2];//get the lang from the id 
    switchLang('menu', lang);//call the function
});
```